# How to change power BI eraser icon´s color in slicer visual?

Tags: colors, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers, eraser

I am trying to change the eraser icon of a slicer in power BI! is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vote to add this feature here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/